# no acces to /admin urls after site migration to local wamp server

Tags: migrations

After migration of my site , any url starting with /admin generate a wamp server 'reinitialization error'.
The migration has been done with drush-dump/archive-restore and is working fine when imported in a VM

what could be the cause and how can i debug it ?

Comment: Does the WAMP server have clean URLs enabled?

Comment: @Nervaccio /?q=admin does the same

Answer (score 0):

Doing a

```
   drush pm-update
```

solved the problem.

Any fine explanation why?